# I want to add to my array within my method without resetting it every time I call the method

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

My array is created and initialised everytime I run this method. How can I keep the array populated until

- moves to another view or
- selects another button (let's call it "reset").

  ```
  - (IBAction)addItemToOrder:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *arrayOrderItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableString *stringOrderItem = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Item: "];
    [stringOrderItem appendString:self.labelProductCode.text];
    [stringOrderItem appendString:@" | Qty: "];
    [stringOrderItem appendString:self.textfieldQuantity.text];
    NSObject *myObj = [[NSObject alloc]init];
    myObj = stringOrderItem;
    [arrayOrderItems addObject:myObj];
    self.textviewOrderTotal.text = stringOrderItem;
    NSLog(@"arrayOrderItems: #records: %d", arrayOrderItems.count);
    NSLog(@"%@", arrayOrderItems);
  }
  ```

Comment: Initialize it outside the method. Probably on init or viewDidLoad.

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to make the array an *instance variable* of the enclosing object.

Comment: thanks Trojanfoe, I am new to programming and not familiar with some  terms like "enclosing object", can you give a little more detail? Much appreciated.

Comment: enclosing object is the class holding your method (probably a viewcontroller in your case). Instance variable means to declare it @interface yourClass: superClass{ NSMutableArray *arrayOrderItems }. You can do it using property as well.

Comment: OK, confused now: I declared '@property NSMuttableArray *testArray' in my ViewController header in between '@interface' and '@end' I then have the following method in the 'VewController' implementation file: '- (IBAction)actionSendOrder:(id)sender {
    NSString *stringTest = [[NSString alloc]init ];
    stringTest = @"Test";
    [testArray addObject:stringTest];
    NSLog(@"%@",testArray.description);
    self.textviewOrderTotal.text = testArray.description;' I find that testArray is NIL.  So should I alloc]init the array and if so, where?

Comment: Confusion over, answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the array as [instance variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable):

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

// MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil != self)
    {
        self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)addItemToOrder:(id)aSender
{
    [self.myArray addObject:@"MyOrder"];
    NSLog(@"%@",testArray.description); 
}

@end
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you Dmitry, I followed that and it worked out. What I had missed was to create an instance at 'init' method. That meant that my custom method could use that instance of the 'array' and add to it during its cycle.